# how do i create a contact us form in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've started using https://github.com/JDutil/contact_us to create a contact use page in my application, however each time I press submit it says its sent a email but it hasn't. Does any one know what to do?

I've changed my contact_us.rb to look like this

```
# Use this hook to configure contact mailer.
ContactUs.setup do |config|

# ==> Mailer Configuration

# Configure the e-mail address which email notifications should be sent from.  If emails must be sent from a verified email address you may set it here.
# Example:
# config.mailer_from = "contact@please-change-me.com"
config.mailer_from = "name@live.com"

# Configure the e-mail address which should receive the contact form email notifications.
config.mailer_to = "name@live.com"

# ==> Form Configuration

# Configure the form to ask for the users name.
config.require_name = true

# Configure the form to ask for a subject.
config.require_subject = true

# Configure the form gem to use.
# Example:
# config.form_gem = 'formtastic'
config.form_gem = 'simple_form_for'
# Configure the redirect URL after a successful submission
config.success_redirect = '/'

# Configure the parent action mailer
# Example:
# config.parent_mailer = "ActionMailer::Base"

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your server/development environment has mail server installed?
If not, you can try using external SMTP server, like Gmail.

Place this code in your `config/environments/development.rb` or config/environments/production.rb` and adjust the values accordingly:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'example.com',
  user_name:            '<username>',
  password:             '<password>',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

Details: [Action Mailer Configuration for Gmail](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail)

Comment: I used this code in my development.rb and changed the values accordingly however I still cant get it to send a email.